# How to give a Subclip a new name in Python using PyAutoGUI?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyautogui

Complete beginner here making my first program with PyAutoGui as I cannot get access to the software's API. My issues are currently being that I am unable to come up with a solution to name each subclip with a different appended letter on the end. The naming convention should go like so, `MI899001~AA`, `MI899001~AB`, `MI899001~AC`, `MI899001~AD`. The only thing that changes is the last letter.

Below is the relevant code I'm currently using for the program I am writing;

```
def naming_promo():
x = string.ascii_uppercase
pyautogui.typewrite('DNH~P336007A' + x[0][0])

for i in range(7):
   if i == 0:
      sub_clip_clean()
   else:
      if i >= 1:
        pyautogui.typewrite('567890qwe', 0.2)
        sub_clip_package()
   naming_promo() # See above Fn for method
   pyautogui.moveTo(646, 404, duration=0.50)
   pyautogui.click()
   move_clips()
```

The **naming_promo()** takes the **ascii_uppercase** and types the first letter. I however can't figure out how to iterate through each character in the string as the For Loop repeats. I've googled many solutions, but I guess I can't get my head around how to do a loop in a loop and increment the x value used each time.

This is my first post so apologies for any etiquette I break. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first answer so apologies for any etiquette I break.
I'm not sure I understand everything here, since there's a few functions in the code that I don't know about. However, are you just looking for something like:

```
def naming_promo(n):
x = string.ascii_uppercase
pyautogui.typewrite('DNH~P336007A' + x[0][n])
```

and further down in your code, simply create a variable and increment it up one after use:

```
m = 0
for i in range(7):
    if i == 0:
        sub_clip_clean()
    else:
        if i >= 1:
            pyautogui.typewrite('567890qwe', 0.2)
            sub_clip_package()
    naming_promo(m) # See above Fn for method
    m += 1
    pyautogui.moveTo(646, 404, duration=0.50)
    pyautogui.click()
    move_clips()
```

Comment: If you wanted to handle more than 26 variables, it's easy to add another variable to the naming_promo function, use two variables (ma and mb) and add an if clause after ma += 1 like
    `if ma > 26:`
        `mb +=1`
        `ma = 0`

Comment: Hi Jim, Thank you for your response. I tried a solution like this before and it returned an index out of range error. I have tried your suggested method and it returned the same error.

I now realise this is because I am incrementing the incorrect value of the index. it should be `x[n][0]` and not `x[0][n]`

Thank you so much for your response this has solved the issue and my program is now working smoothly. I also understand what I was doing wrong too.